# SQL query to compare earlier values in the Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

We have a log table where user processes log entries (`success`/`failure`/`timeout`) each time they run. For e.g.

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | username | status  |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | saqib    | success |
|  2 | mary     | timeout |
|  3 | scott    | timeout |
|  4 | saqib    | success |
|  5 | mary     | timeout |
|  6 | scott    | timeout |
|  7 | saqib    | timeout |
|  8 | mary     | timeout |
|  9 | scott    | timeout |
+----+----------+---------+
```

We would like to get a usernames which have had a success in the past the but the latest entry for them was a timeout. (saqib in the above example)

Is there single query that can do this? Right now we are doing this using a PHP script, but would like to use mySQL query for this.

Thanks

Comment: Is the only chronological element in the table the id?

Comment: You shouldn't use `id` for chronological access. IDs can be updated or (more common) be inserted in non-chronological order. What's wrong with using a `datetime` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cddc6/2/0)

```
SELECT DISTINCT m1.username
FROM
(
  SELECT s1.username, s1.ids 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT username, MAX(id) as ids
    FROM MyTable 
    GROUP BY username
  ) AS s1
  INNER JOIN MyTable AS s2
  ON s1.ids = s2.id
  WHERE s2.status = 'timeout'  
) AS m1
INNER JOIN MyTable m2 ON m1.username = m2.username
AND m2.status = 'success'
```

Comment: This will also return users that have a timeout and later a success. I think the OP does not want that.

Comment: **@ypercube**, you are right and I made the necessary modifications to my answer to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the latest `id` for each `username` and then `JOIN` it with the original table checking if there were entries for each user with `status` `success` and `id` less then maximum.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM ( SELECT username
             , MAX(id) as ind
       FROM tbl
       GROUP BY username
     ) x JOIN tbl t ON t.username = x.username 
                   AND t.id = x.ind 
                   AND t.status IN ('timeout', 'failure')
                   AND EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                                FROM tbl 
                                WHERE username = x.username
                                  AND id < x.ind  
                                  AND status = 'success'
                              )
```

[**Example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82836/5)

Answer (score 2):

I would use exists for this problem. Exists are nice because they generally are faster than joining to the table. Unrelated, but I would recommend using a time stamp as opposed to relying on the id number.

```
Select username
From    table t1

Where   t1.status = 'timeout'

and     exists (Select 1
                From table t2
                Where t1.username = t2.username
                and     t2.status = 'success'
                Limit 1)

and     not exists (Select 1
                    From table t3
                    Where t3.username = t1.username
                    and     t3.id > t1.id
                        Limit 1);
```

Comment: `TOP 1` is not valid in MySql.

Comment: **@Jenn**, Your query should return `saqib` but it is not returning anything [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23e65/26/0).

Comment: @Linger Right, they had `<` instead of `>`. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table to itself:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' -> ', a.id, b.id) SEPARATOR ','), a.username
FROM t a
   JOIN t b USING (username)
WHERE b.id > a.id
   AND (a.status = 'success' 
   AND  b.status = 'timeout')
GROUP BY a.username;
```

This shows all pairs of previous success to later timeout.

[`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e26b8/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 UserName, max(id)
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE 
    UserName IN (SELECT UserName from Table where Status = 'Success')
 GROUP BY UserName
    Having MAX(id) = (select max(id) from username where status = 'timeout')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by joining 2 subqueries 1 for the maximum id per user with success status which will satisfy the condition *which have had a success in the past* and 2 for the max id to get users with latest timeout last comparison part `t1.id < t2.id` will satisfy the user should have success in past

```
select * from
(select `username`,max(id) id 
from t 
where `status` ='success'
group by `username`
) t1
join
(
select `username`,max(id) id 
from t 
where `status` ='timeout'
group by `username`
  ) t2
on(t1.username = t2.username)
where t1.id < t2.id
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaeb73/5)

Another solution this will be much cleaner bu just using one query with max and case

```
select
username,
max(case when `status` ='success' then id else 0 end) success,
max(case when `status` ='timeout' then id else 0 end) timeout
from t
group by username
having timeout > success
and success > 0
```

### [Demo 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaeb73/7)